# Redirect website to inner links

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a multilanguage website with this structure `http://www.url.com/en/`, `http://www.url.com/it/`, `http://www.url.com/pt/` etc.
My problem now is that when you access the link url.com I will have 3 redirects.

1. To `http://url.com`
2. To `http://www.url.com`
3. To `http://www.url.com/en/`

How can I do to have only 2 redirects? If you access `http://url.com` to redirect to `http://www.url.com/en/`
In my htaccess file I have this lines.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.url.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This one redirects from url.com to `http://www.url.com`. After this is redirected a php file script recognized the domain and it redirects again to /en/

```
$url= strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"/".$lang."/");
if($url!==0){ Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.url.com/en/" );  }
```

After that I have some conditions to check if you are in another language.

```
if($lang == "pt"){$langcheck = "pt"}
```

My links are created like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/$ index.php?page=index&lang=$1 [L]
```

So what should I write in htaccess to work this for each language. Because if I change the RewriteRule to `url.com/en/` the other languages doesn't work anymore.

Comment: i am sorry, i can't get it how do you getting language and how do you redirecting.

Comment: When you enter to url.com I check into functions.php if the URL is different from url.com/en/. If is different I redirect to the URL url.com/en/. This condition is only if you acces the link url.com, but if you type url.com/it/ I see that there is another language. My problem is when you acces url.com ( I would like to be redirected to url.com/en/ for the first time, not to www.url.com and after that to www.url.com/en/.

Answer (score 0):

How to accomplish this depends upon where you get the language string from, how many languages you want to support, and how complex this interaction should be.

If it's just a couple of languages, and you want to use the browser settings for this, you might be able to use [htaccess rewrites](http://tech-blog.borychowski.com/index.php/2009/03/htaccess/redirect-according-to-browser-language-mod-rewrite-and-http_accept_language/) for this.

However, if you have more than just a few languages, want to let users select their own language in the site itself, or anything more complex than the above. Well, then you need to do everything in PHP.
This means removing the htaccess redirect for the missing "www" domain, then checking for this in the PHP code. Before, or after, you check for the language selected. Using both checks to determine the link to redirect to, before actually redirecting.

Meta example:

```
// We want all users to use the domain with www.
$redir = '';
if (substr ($url, 0, 3)) != 'www') {
    $redir .= 'www.';
}

// If user has selected a different language, we need to redirect for that too.
if (!empty ($lang)) {
    $redir .= "{$base_url}/{$lang}/";
}

// If $redir isn't empty, redirect the user.
// PS: Always remember to use `die()` after a `header()` redirect!
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tested and I removed the redirect from htaccess and at first byte is working perfectly, but in my inner links is not working (is working with http://url.com/innerl and with www.url.com/innerl). It's a lot of work for my website to make the redirect for all the links. I'm trying to find a way to do this with htaccess.

Comment: You don't need to make a redirect for all of the links individually with PHP. The only thing you do need is something similar to the above, which tests all of the requests to the site. If you have multiple entry points, then you can just make a function of the above code, include it in each page and run it. DRY, after all.